# Pilot TV series end in sea level rising

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi

I am trying to recall the name of a TV series years ago, possible just a pilot episode. Following is what I can remember:

- A group of scientist tracking some huge sea creature with satellite tracking device. The huge sea creature also appear in river. The creature seems to emit some kind of EMP field which will render all digital camera unless.
- The scientist also discovered a new kind of plant specimen, which seems to feed on radiation, in a safe located on a island or a boat?
- There is a very wealthy man/corporation hired a female scientist doing secret genetic research. The wealthy man also has a specimen of the plant.
- That female scientist on the other hand secretly contacting the scientist mention above and passing out her research data, which is linked to the sea creature. She later met them using a glider. She is killed after the meeting.
- The episode end in water flooding into the city.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of [Surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(TV_series)) from 2005. It had mysterious sea creatures which emitted EMP, and ended with a flood. Only fifteen episodes.

Comment: Excellent!!! I didn't expect answer so fast!! I checked the wikipedia link and it is exactly it!! Too bad the series end so prematurely.

Comment: Glad to assist! I really liked it when it was on TV. Was sad to see it end so soon.